# Camel set header before from

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have an endpoint and want to set a header before it is sent to the API.

```
Stream.of("a", "b").forEach(id) -> {
    from("azure-storage-blob://devstoreaccount1/hotfolder?serviceClient=#blobServiceClient&operation=listBlobs")
    .routeId(id)
    .autoStartup(false)
    .tracing()
     // this should happen before the the azure call
    .setHeader("MyHeader", () -> id)
    .process(exchange -> {
        ArrayList<BlobItem> items = exchange.getIn().getBody(ArrayList.class);
        for (BlobItem blobItem : items) {
            System.out.println(blobItem.getName());
        }
    });
}
```

Later when the Context is booted I start the route somewhere else with

```
final Route route = camelContext.getRoute("a");
ServiceHelper.startService(route.getConsumer());
```

Now it tried to introduce a new route to trigger the old one and set header before.

```
from("direct:intermediate")
  .noAutoStartup()
  .routeId("intermediate")
  .to("direct:hf");

from("direct:hf")
  .setHeader("MyHeader", () -> id)
  .to("azure-storage-blob://devstoreaccount1/hotfolder?serviceClient=#blobServiceClient&operation=listBlobs")
  .process(exchange -> {
      ArrayList<BlobItem> items = exchange.getIn().getBody(ArrayList.class);
      for (BlobItem blobItem : items) {
          System.out.println(blobItem.getName());
      }
  });

final Route route = camelContext.getRoute("intermediate");
ServiceHelper.startService(route.getConsumer());
```

But the route doesn't do anything.
Is there a way with camel to do something before from?

Comment: What is the purpose of the header? Is printing of the file names working for you in either example?

Comment: The Header is to set some of the CamelAzureStorageBlob* headers. Namely CamelAzureStorageBlobListBlobOptions with prefix (). If i set prefix in the url as request param it is not passend to the endpoint. I checked and both do not work actually.

Comment: that should work to set your headers prior to sending to the azure-data-storage-blob component.  Based on the docs and the code, it will pick up the CamelAzureStorageBlobListBlobOptions header attached to the camel message.

Comment: Seems like the problem is starting the route itself. If I start direct:hf with a timer instead it works. But unfortunately I need to work with noAutoStartup.

Comment: I don't understand why prefix is not picked up from the requestParameter (e.g. "&prefix=test". In BlobConfigurationOptionsProxy i can see that it is reading from the Exchange header only). This would fix all workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set a header before from simply because there is no message yet.